# Does anyone know where one can buy a hebrewbooks harddrive?

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, jewish-books

I am looking to purchase a hebrewbooks hard drive (It may very well come handy here!).

Does anyone know where can I buy it online? (eichlers, etc.)

Comment: Umm...what is a hebrewbooks hard drive?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think it means all the books on Hebrewbooks.org on one device.

Comment: If the site doesn't sell it, it may be in violation of their terms of service to do so. Have you looked in to Bar Ilan?

Comment: @YaakovKuperman I have seen "official" harddrives from them. Also see [here](http://data.hebrewbooks.org/hd/faq.html)

Comment: @DoubleAA It's a copy of their website (with all the seforim) on a harddrive (so they load faster and work without internet).

Comment: I have one from 2006 (11,000 seforim). As I can get most anything from the website, I'm willing to part with mine for a song as long as that song has lyrics which include cash offers.

Comment: If you're willing to spend the time doing it, why not just go through their site, Sefer by Sefer, and download every PDF?

Comment: @donielf because I don't have the time for_ that._

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just had a nice long chat on their website with Chaim Rosenberg, the director The Society for the Preservation of Hebrew Books. He said they are currently working on a new HebrewBooks drive, that should be available soon. So apparently, there is none available now. He was not sure if the new one would be on-site or in-stores.

Based on that, I'd say it'll be available in [six to eight weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/168660).

Comment: Now, _that_ is good research.

Comment: Good thing I didn't hold my breath :)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I think my time estimate is still pretty spot-on.

Comment: @HodofHod ?.....

Answer (score 1):

I found [this ad](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2010/03/great-deal-on-hebrewbooks-hard-drive.html) on a blog from last year.  The links he posts to buy online are dead, but I would use the contact info on the ad to try and get ahold of it from them directly. [This old post from a different blog](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2006/11/new-hard-drive.html) says to either contact them directly or go to a certain set of seforim stores in NY.  That being said, this seems like a lot of money to shell out for something you can get the equivalent of for free online (seforim blog says it costs $300), so I'd only get it if you truly need the whole library offline.

Comment: Maybe that's why they stopped making them, or at least stopped advertising them.

Comment: @Double AA Maybe. You'd think there's still a market with all of the people who (at least as far as they say) don't use the internet at home.

Comment: @Shmuel Brin Download the pdf of stuff you use frequently. Thats what I do for the Shas I use from them.

Comment: ( I realize that takes time, but do it once overnight and you'll have it in the morning )

Comment: @ShmuelBrin really? I was planning on writing a script. Their robots.txt seems a bit out of date.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Ahh, good find. I missed that clause in their terms. Also, funny how the all-caps part is supposed to make you look, but it makes me skip it.